# ClassNotFoundException with Maven and Java

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, maven, jar

I make a little desktop application and I use the MySQL connector to work with databases. Previously I have added the MySQL connector to the classpath.

After, i have added the mysql connector dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.29</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

The build is a success, but when i launch my .jar file from the command line, this error appears :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

When i launch my program with `java -cp mysql-connector-java-5.1.29.jar -jar NameOfJar.jar`, there is no problem, the program starts normally, but ideally I would like to "pack" the connector or have a 'lib' folder, instead of type `java -cp mysql [...]` (double click on the file opens the application).

Thanks,
OverSpeed301

Comment: Note `<scope>compile</scope>`

Comment: As @SotiriosDelimanolis pointed out, just remove that tag; it is telling Maven that the `mysql-connector-java` dependency is only needed at compile time, but not at runtime (which is not the case here :-))

Comment: @watery But since compile scope is the default there shouldn't be any effect when you remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, you can also use the shade plug in:

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactSet>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>org.slf4j*</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </artifactSet>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

it creates an additional jar with all dependencies except the ones you explicitly exclude as show in the example above (org.slf4j*). Be aware that this replaces your regular jar with a fatter jar containing all dependencies. If you need both, you should use the maven-assembly

Answer (score 0):

Maven comes with support to produce a jar with all required dependencies but you need to configure the assembly plugin correctly.

If you add the following to the build section of your pom.xml

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                    <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

When you run `mvn package` you should get a version of your jar with all dependencies packaged within.

For my example I produced the following:

1. target/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
2. target/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar

See the Maven [assembly plugin documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks you, I have tried both solutions, it works beautifully ! :)